# Wordpress and mod_pagespeed – pagespeed CSS not found

Tags: css, wordpress, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have Wordpress 4.8 with Shopkeeper 2.1 theme running on Apache 2.4, Debian 8. After turning on mod_pagespeed I got a strange problem, on first load in any browser my website looks like CSS is incomplete – which is right, I can see in inspector **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) _.pagespeed.co.4QvMMP-E9N.css"**. After reloading or continue browsing everything goes fine. I think that it's that part of CSS of my theme which originally goes inline. Anyone know how to solve that?

Here's my pagespeed.conf filters:

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters add_head
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_heads
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_meta_tags
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters flatten_css_imports
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_to_head
ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_above_scripts
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters make_google_analytics_async
ModPagespeedEnableFilters responsive_images,resize_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters responsive_images_zoom
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
```

Comment: hi, did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, I didn't. Just migrated to Nginx and another theme, no pagespeed now